# Order of an element of a safe prime

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

So, in the problem I have a safe prime 263, and e is the order of 11 modulo 263, I found the order to be 131. I know that safe primes are $p=2q+1$ and $q=(p-1)/2$ and in this case the q of 263 is 131. I'm trying to put the pieces together as to why must be e>100 but I feel like I'm missing something. Is 11 an element of 263 and is this why? Or is it just because the order is the smallest positive integer for in which $a^m = e$?

Comment: There are only four divisors of $p-1$. Can you see why its order can't be 1 or 2?

Comment: @JasonM yes, only 1 has the order of 1, and -1 has the order of 2... I think. And the four divisors are 1, 2, q, and 2q right?

Comment: Yes exactly, so since $11$ is neither $1$ nor $-1$, it must have order $q$ or $2q$, both of which are greater than $100$.

Comment: Aah, okay, that's what I was missing, thank you!